# How to find one person driving path is in another person driving path in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

The location is like A - B- C- D.

The person X is driving from A-D and another person Y is driving from B-C,
How the person x comes to know, the person Y is driving on his way?

Using google map, Rootlocation finder in android...

Like OLA and Uber apps finding nearest person, how to find it programmatically.

Comment: you find track using GPS

Comment: You would start by doing a design; followed by writing code. Not by dropping requirements here and hopping that other people tell you how to implement your own idea.

Comment: I'm just asking any feature in android to implement this. I have developed almost 90%. Only in this point I want some ideas/features in android. I have tried the "isLocationOnPath" in PolyUtil class, but I'm not getting, same way any other feature is in android?? just tell this is enogh...

Comment: `How to find the person x, the Y is on his way?` ??? What do you want? Very unclear. Please describe better. Person x?